# Yii - How to cause Yii to republish to the assets folder

Tags: yii, assets

Yii question.

On my development machine, the required JQuery files for the application were present in a subfolder under the assets folder. However, when I copied the application to my test server, JQuery files were missing in the folder yii looked for them. I kept getting errors such as '../assets/db0e5a94/jquery.ba-bbq.js' 404 not found, etc.

I emptied the assets folder, and now all my CSS files etc. are reported missing. Is there any way I can cause Yii to republish to the assets folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting the contents of assets folder. Yii will republish it

Comment: I tried that - doesn't work. It republishes a few files, not others that are required.

Comment: Check your assets folder permissions (or some errors in log file). Maybe yii don't have permission to write files to this folder? And give code how you using css file in your project (registering throw CClientScript or just inserting link in html <head> part?

Comment: @ARV: The problem is caused by something that generates the "stale" paths into `assets/`. You need to find what that is.

Comment: @briiC.lv Yii does write *some* of the files, but not all of them. Also, I am using CClientScript to insert CSS files, but even the files inserted by Zii widgets etc. are missing.

Comment: there something non-yii related going on.. hmm. Maybe you did something with yii framework folder? Download latest and try to use that. Does your apache error.log or yii application.log say anything?

Comment: @ARV: Did you get the solution for this problem? If yes, Please share.

Answer (score 9):

Simply delete all sub-directories in the assets folder and clear your browser cache. Do not delete the assets directory or you will have to set the write permissions again.

Comment: There's no programmatic way to invalidate all old cache files?

Answer (score 4):

in **components/Controller.php** add the following function:

```
protected function beforeAction($action){
    if(defined('YII_DEBUG') && YII_DEBUG){
        Yii::app()->assetManager->forceCopy = true;
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: For Yii2 this can be done through configuration, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26439007/885397

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to have your assets back is to manually copy them from `framework` directory back. I know it is not the best way to do it, but it should help you while you find a better solution.

Comment: I'd rather not do this, since the folder names are different. What's the proper Yii-way of doing this - that's the question!

Comment: Good question. I had the same problem and I resolved my way, but I totally agree that is not right way.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your hosting service provider to disable SAFE_MODE in php.ini. Then remove asstes directory together with its sub files and folders and create it again. Make sure that you set CHMOD to 0777 for the new directory you just created.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same problem. After uploading the respective files to the server i changed the file permission to 755 in the server. Then it worked.