# Is there a way to force Yii to reload module assets on every request?

Tags: php, yii, refresh, reload, assets

My website is divided into separate modules. Every module has it's own specific css or js files in `/protected/modules/my_module/assets/css` or `js` for js files. Yiis assets manager creates folder when I first use page that uses my assets. 
Unfortunately if I change sth in my files - Yii does not reload my css or js file. I have to manually delete `/projects/assets` folder. It is really annoying when you are developing the app.

Is there a way to force Yii to reload assets every request?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `components/Controller.php` add the following (or adjust an existing `beforeAction`):

```
protected function beforeAction($action){
    if(defined('YII_DEBUG') && YII_DEBUG){
        Yii::app()->assetManager->forceCopy = true;
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

What this does it that before any actions are started, the application will check to see if you are in debug mode, and if so, will set the asset manager to forcibly recopy all the assets on every page load.

See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager#forceCopy-detail

I have not tested this, but based on the documentation I believe it should work fine.

Note: The placement of this code within `beforeAction` is just an example of where to put it. You simply need to set the `forceCopy` property to true before any calls to `publish()`, and placing it in `beforeAction` should accomplish that goal.

Comment: Hint: The `defined(YII_DEBUG)` is not neccessary - it will always be defined as either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Yii2 there is a much simpler solution through configuration.

Add the following to your `'config/web.php'`:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    // ...
    $config['components']['assetManager']['forceCopy'] = true;
}
```

This forces the [AssetManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html) to copy all folders on each run.

Comment: .. or you can simply add `'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG,` at **assetManager** section in **components**

Answer (score 3):

An alternatively solution is to publish your module assets like this:

```
Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($path, false, -1, YII_DEBUG);
```

The fourth parameter enforces a copy of your assets, even if they where already published. 
See the manual on [publish()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager#publish-detail) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Re-publishing assets on every request potentially takes a lot of resources and is unnessecary for development.

- For development, it's much easier to use the `linkAssets` feature of
  CClientScript. Assets are published as symbolic link directories, and
  never have to be regenerated. See:
  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager#linkAssets-detail
- For staging/production, you should make clearing the assets/ folder
  part of your update routine/script.

Only fall back to one of the other solutions if for some reason you cannot use symbolic links on your development machine (not very likely).

Comment: Very interesting solution. I'll look into it but it seems very promising and indeed faster than publish assets every request.

Answer (score 2):

In YII 1 in config we have:

```
'components'=> [
...
 'assetManager' => array(
            'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG,
...
)
...

]
```