# CSS update issues - Yii/PHP

Tags: php, css, yii

I thought this would be a quick fix, but apparently not.

I've cleared my cache, changed browsers, performed hard reloads, duplicated/renamed the file, and still the CSS does not update. I'm in a YII framework and when I use the Chrome Inspect tool, it shows 2 different versions of the same thing:

**What it should be**
[image: What it should be]

**What it is**
[image: What it is]

Any help here? Deployments to the server are working just fine but perhaps it's the server caching?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of the relevant parts?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem relates to YII [CAssetManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager) then you can check this posts:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/311/assetmanager-clearing-browser-s-cache-on-site-update/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13897-disable-cache-for-js-and-css-files/

PS: CAssetManager is normally used to manage assets (JS, CSS, ...) for components and libraries, but also for YII views.

Answer (score 0):

In what css file are you working? if you're editing the css files deployed by the Yii assetmanager you should empty the assets folder or do a forceReload see ([Is there a way to force Yii to reload module assets on every request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614364/is-there-a-way-to-force-yii-to-reload-module-assets-on-every-request))

Answer (score 0):

Please check you are putting css files in same order in both environment.

if you are using different order than it is possible that browser takes different properties for both environments.

browser gives priorities to the css files in **DESCENDING order**.

like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> //h1{ color: black; }
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css"> //h1{ color: white; }
```

priority will be given to app.css so if you are looking to your browser it will give white color for h1 element